# How can I process through a list and put its contents into a new parent and child object?

Tags: c#

I have data that I put into a list like this:

```
var data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("topic1 - subtopic1");
            data.Add("topic1 - subtopic2");
            data.Add("topic1 - subtopic3");
            data.Add("topic2 - subtopic4");
            data.Add("topic3 - subtopic5");
```

I have two classes:

```
public partial class Topic {
   public Topic()
   {
      this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
   }
   public int TopicId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic {
   public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
   public int Number { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int TopicId { get; set; }
   public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a simple way that I can go though each record of my list and insert the text to the left of 
the "-" into Topic and the text to the right of the "-" into SubTopic? The problem for me is how can I handle the parent child relationship so that with this data I end up with a Topic object with just three records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use LINQ:

```
var separator = new[] { "-" };
var topics = data.Select(s => s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(strings => strings[0])
    .Select(grouping => new Topic
    {
        Name = grouping.Key,
        SubTopics = grouping.Select(s => new SubTopic {Name = s[1]}).ToList()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for this very good example. I think I can learn a lot by studying the way you have done this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a dictionary. Something like this,

```
Dictionary<string,Topic> topics = new Dictionary<string,Topic>();
foreach(string topic in data)
{
string[] values = topic.split(new string[]{"-"});
if( !topic.ContainsKey(values[0]) )
  topic.Add(values[0], new Topic());
Topic topic = topics [values[0];
topic.Name = values[0];
topic.SubTopics.Add( new SubTopic(){Name = values[1]};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new List<string>();
data.Add("topic1 - subtopic1");
data.Add("topic1 - subtopic2");
data.Add("topic1 - subtopic3");
data.Add("topic2 - subtopic4");
data.Add("topic3 - subtopic5");

var memo = new Dictionary<string, Topic>();

foreach (var parts in data.Select(item => item.Split('-').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToArray()))
{
    if (!memo.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
    {
        memo.Add(parts[0], new Topic {Name = parts[0]});
    }
    memo[parts[0]].SubTopics.Add(new SubTopic { Name = parts[1], Topic = memo[parts[0]] });
}

var result = memo.Values.ToList();
```